# How to implement QR reader in HTML 5?

Tags: javascript, css, html, web-applications, qr-code

I am developing a web application, in which Iam using QR code reader script, I am using the following tutorial,

```
http://dwa012.github.io/html5-qrcode/
```

And this is the script,

```
 <div  class="center" id="reader" style="width:300px;height:250px;">
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#reader').html5_qrcode(function(data){
         // do something when code is read
    },
    function(error){
        //show read errors 
    }, function(videoError){
        //the video stream could be opened
    }
);




</script>
</div>
```

I am able to access the webcam, but there is no display. I could see the LED switching on when accessing, so the webcam is ready but there is no display. Help me in getting the display.

Comment: Does it work when you run the demo on the demopage you lik to?

Comment: Yes the demo has worked !!

Comment: I am wondering if you successfully made it to work as I am trying hard as well